# Isolating time and date in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have date and time formatted as follows:

```
Get-Date -f "M/d/yyyy h:mm tt"
```

Which looks like this

```
4/16/2019 4:19 PM
```

So now, I want to select only the ones where the time is greater than 8:00 AM and 5:00 PM... but the date means nothing, I want the same times select across every date.

What do I need to do to use the where object selection on the time but be indiscriminate when it comes to the date?

Comment: Can you select it before formatting? *greater than 8:00 AM and 5:00 PM* Did you mean between?

Comment: @PetSerAl Yes I did mean between sorry I should have made that clearer

Comment: You could pipe an array of datetimes to `| where-object { $_.hour -gt 8 -and $_.hour -lt 17 }`

Comment: http://sigkillit.com/2015/04/28/determine-if-a-date-is-between-two-dates/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always differentiate between a [datetime] and it's locale/user settings depending (string) representation.

You can only calculate with the `[datetime]` type. To isolate the time component:

```
> ([datetime]::now).TimeOfDay


Days              : 0
Hours             : 19
Minutes           : 7
Seconds           : 8
Milliseconds      : 413
Ticks             : 688284139558
TotalDays         : 0,796625161525463
TotalHours        : 19,1190038766111
TotalMinutes      : 1147,14023259667
TotalSeconds      : 68828,4139558
TotalMilliseconds : 68828413,9558
```

Or similarly

```
> (Get-Date).TimeOfDay


Days              : 0
Hours             : 19
Minutes           : 7
Seconds           : 34
Milliseconds      : 841
Ticks             : 688548416521
TotalDays         : 0,796931037640046
TotalHours        : 19,1263449033611
TotalMinutes      : 1147,58069420167
TotalSeconds      : 68854,8416521
TotalMilliseconds : 68854841,6521
```

As soon as a format (`Get-Date -f "h:m:s"` or `.ToString('T')` ) get's involved you've got a string which first has to be converted back to a `[datetime]`.

**As per @PetSerAls valuable hint you can use:**

```
$CheckDateTime = Get-Date
if(($CheckDateTime | 
    Where-Object TimeOfDay -ge (New-TimeSpan -Hours 8)  |
    Where-Object TimeOfDay -lt (New-TimeSpan -Hours 17) )){
      "{0:M/d/yyyy h:mm tt} is in working hours" -f $CheckDateTime
    } else {
      "{0:M/d/yyyy h:mm tt} is NOT in working hours" -f $CheckDateTime
    }
```

To check if the TimeOfDay component falls within the defined working hours.

Comment: What is wrong with [`TimeOfDay`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.datetime.timeofday)?

Comment: @PetSerAl Just didn't think of it - it has the same output. So to compare if a time is before/after `8:00 AM`/`5:00 PM` you've to express that as one of the `.Total` properties anyway.

Comment: With two time request clock can, in principle, pass midnight between them, and you will get negative time. Also, `TimeSpan` can be compared directly. Using `.Total` properties is not required: `Get-Date | ? TimeOfDay -ge (New-TimeSpan -Hours 8) | ? TimeOfDay -lt (New-TimeSpan -Hours 17) | Get-Date -f 'M/d/yyyy h:mm tt'`.

Comment: Excellent this gives me what I need! Thank you @LotPings and PetSerAls so much :)